# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame, but not slice

Tags: python, pandas

I read several similar question on stackoverflow, but I still don't understand, I'm doing:

```
dictionnaire = {}
for i, valeur in enumerate(streets):
    dictionnaire[valeur] = i+1
for index, elem in enumerate(home_data['Street']):
    home_data['Street'][index]=dictionnaire[elem]
```

Which seems to work but I have that warning, I tried that:

```
dictionnaire = {}
for i, valeur in enumerate(streets):
    dictionnaire[valeur] = i+1
streets=home_data.Street
for index, elem in enumerate(streets):
    home_data['Street'][index]=dictionnaire[elem]
```

thinking it's because I'm setting `home_data['Street'][index]` whie browsing it, but I get this error:

```
KeyError: 'Pave'
```

'Pave' is a value of `home_data['Street']`, that exists in `dictionnaire`

Comment: `home_data.loc[index, 'Street'] = something`. Though your code is better with `map`: `home_data['Street'] = home_data['Street'].map(dictionnaire)`.

Comment: I realy hate python... But thank you !